# PyCharm Jupyter got messed up

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter

I'm a newbie to PyCharm and Jupyter. After installing Anaconda, I changed PyCharm project interpreter to Anaconda's python.exe, then I deleted the old virtual env folder where my Jupyter used to run (due to very limited disk space).

Now when I run Jupyter, it shows the following error message:

> Error running 'python': Cannot run program "C:\my_work_dir\venv\Scripts\python.exe" (in directory "C:\my_work_dir\python"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I understand the error message means that it cannot find the path. But I don't understand why it keeps looking for the old path while I have changed my project interpreter's path. Please help!

Comment: you need to specify manually the path for jupyter notebook so jupyter can look for the location of the kernel, now you don’t have a specified kernel and this is the issue.

Comment: the problem is, I don't know where to manually specify the path for jupyter in Pycharm... I tried settings but couldn't find a way to do so.

Comment: you need to add more details, at least post the settings window with the Project Interpreter ... you new environment seems is missing the ipython ... so you need to install it in order to have the kernel to run under your new venv ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install **jupyter** for the *project interpreter* or the **venv** you use as follow:

```
pip install jupyter
```

> Note: This is what I suspect is the problem because **Anaconda** has
>   all this installed by default but for manual python install you need
>   to install all this packages(for **ipython** is required *jupyter*) in
>   order to have it work.